# assign global variable value from local variable of template using xsl

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
 `<xsl:template match="xhtml:style">
      <xsl:variable name="text" select="text()"/>
  </xsl:template>`
```

This is my template having local variable whose value would be the internal styles of html and i want these internal style data to be a global variable value so that i could access this value in other templates for further processing.

I want to use internal styles data for further processing so i think of using this approach.

How could i insert value to global variable from local variable of a template.???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could i insert value to global variable from local variable of a
>   template.???

**This is a FAQ -- you can't.**

XSLT is a functional programming language and among other things this means that a the value of a variable, once defined, cannot be modified.

**You can achieved what you want in a much simpler way** -- define the wanted global variable simply as (a child of `xsl:stylesheet'):

```
<xsl:variable name="vYourGlobalVar" select="(//xhtml:style)[1]/text()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitre, it worked out excellently.
Need to ask you one more doubt
If i am having a variable "styletext" and having value as "c0 c1 c3" and i want to process same code for each C0,c1,c3 value of variable;
what should i do?
Please Suggest...!!

Comment: Need to ask you one more doubt.If i am having a variable "styletext" and having value as "c0 c1 c3" and i want to process same code for each C0,c1,c3 value of variable;as these c0,c1,c3 is having data in them.
like-
<xsl:variable name="styletext">c0{font-weight:Bold}.c2{color:pink;}.c3{font-size:28pt;}</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template name="body>
<xsl:variable name="text">c0 c2 c3 c4</xsl:variable>
I want to retreive this Text variable Value as c0 then access some code then c2 then access same code and so on...
Please suggest

Comment: @DivyaGarg, As I hinted: Please, ask a *new* question -- many people read questions and will be able to answer, however much fewer people read comments and answer them.